# Hadoop Map Reduce History Server UI - unable to find job logs (but log exists at hdfs)

Tags: java, logging, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

In the Hadoop JobHistory WEB UI, I see all applications, running, killed, finished(succeeded), etc. However, I can not access **some** of the MapReduce jobs tracking URL history logs.

When I run `hadoop fs -ls /user/history/done/2023/08/31/00003/` command, I see job_XXXXXX_404 jhist and xml logs. So log exists but web ui not found job. (When I click the history button, (http://server:19888/jobhistory/job/job_XXXXXX_4047 page) only one sentence appears: Not found: job_XXXXXX_4047 )

hadoop-hdfs-historyserver-XXX.Log:
**ERROR** `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.CachedHistoryStorage: Unable to find job job_XXXXXX_4047`

Then I changed log level INFO to DEBUG:

hadoop-hdfs-historyserver-XXX.Log:

```
DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.CachedHistoryStorage: Looking for Job job_XXXXXX_4047
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager: Scanning intermediate_dirs
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager: Scan not needed of hdfs://ha-cluster:8020/user/history/done_intermediate/hdfs
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager: Scan not needed of hdfs://ha-cluster:8020/user/history/done_intermediate/root
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.CachedHistoryStorage: Unable to find job job_XXXXXX_4047
```

Some other jobs, hadoop-hdfs-historyserver-XXX.Log logs like

```
DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.CachedHistoryStorage: Looking for Job job_XXXXXX_4047
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager: Scanning intermediate_dirs
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager: Scan not needed of hdfs://ha-cluster:8020/user/history/done_intermediate/hdfs
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager: Scanning intermediate dir hdfs://ha-cluster:8020/user/history/done_intermediate/root
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager: Found 0 files
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.CachedHistoryStorage: Unable to find job job_XXXXXX_4047
```

[Hadoop HistoryFileManager.java](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/v2/hs/HistoryFileManager.java#L1087):

```
...
  public HistoryFileInfo getFileInfo(JobId jobId) throws IOException {
    // FileInfo available in cache.
    HistoryFileInfo fileInfo = jobListCache.get(jobId);
    if (fileInfo != null) {
      return fileInfo;
    }
    // OK so scan the intermediate to be sure we did not lose it that way
    scanIntermediateDirectory();
    fileInfo = jobListCache.get(jobId);
    if (fileInfo != null) {
      return fileInfo;
    }

    // Intermediate directory does not contain job. Search through older ones.
    fileInfo = scanOldDirsForJob(jobId);
    if (fileInfo != null) {
      return fileInfo;
    }
    return null;
  }
...
```

Finally, I restarted the history server service(`mapred --daemon stop historyserver, mapred --daemon start historyser`), and I saw the logs. But I'm tired of restarting the service. Why can't the history server find the job logs?